# How to run function by getting option default values?

Tags: angular

I have a drop down box with the following HTML code:

```
<select #select id="id" class="class" (change)="onChange($event)">
    <option value="1"> 1 </option>
    <option value="2"> 2 </option>
</select>
```

I also got an input box to get user input:

```
onChange(){
    if(value==1){
      //do something}
    }else{
      // do another thing
}
```

After user input, user can get the result by select an option (1or2).
How can I keep running option 1 as a default? Right now, I can run option 1 event after user change to option 2 
first.

Is it possible to get `<option>` value in the `<input>` by using 
`onChange()` too?

Answer (score 0):

You can set a default value if you add the `selected` attribute to one of your options. It should look like this: `<option value="1" selected> 1 </option>`.[Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/How-can-I-set-the-default-value-for-an-HTML-select-element) is the link to the solution I found.

Change **onChange()** to **onChange(event: any)** in your ts file, because you won't get any value if the user is selecting another value in the select input. The selected value is located in `event.target.value`.

If you want a form with angular, then this link will help you building one.

Comment: right now i can get values if user change option .i try the selected before ,but it doesn't work to me since there are no change, so the event of option 1 cannot be trigger from the beginning. i think i have to get option values first after user input